# How to put my size and name of a file into dictionary

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, file-io

I have 3 files `size_1.py`  `size_2.py`  `size.py`

My Code is below

```
import os
result = {}
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            size =  (os.path.getsize(thefile),thefile)
           # print (size)
            result[size[0]] = size[1]
print (result)
```

My output

```
{315: './size.py', 249: './size_1.py'}
```

My Desired Output

```
{315:['./size.py']
249 : ['size_1.py', './size_2.py']
}
```

Comment: can you explain better the relationship between your input and your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add an if check to see if the key (size) exists in dictionary already:

```
import os
result = {}
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            size =  (os.path.getsize(thefile),thefile)
           # print (size)
        if size[0] in result:
            result[size[0]].append(size[1])
        else:
            result[size[0]] = [size[1]]
print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You only put strings in the values of `result` dictionary. You should put lists of strings. To do so, I suggest you to use `defaultdict` class to define directly a dictionary with lists as values, which is more comfortable.
I may also suggest you some minor improvements in your code for readability, as follows:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            size =  os.path.getsize(thefile)
            result[size].append(thefile)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a defaultdict of list to easily do this, just append values instead of assigning.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            size =  (os.path.getsize(thefile),thefile)
           # print (size)
            result[size[0]].append(size[1])
print (result)
```

---

Alternatively, without using defaultdict:

```
import os
result = {}
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            size =  (os.path.getsize(thefile),thefile)
           # print (size)
            result.setdefault(size[0], []).append(size[1])
print (result)
```